# Determining $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x +h) - f(x)}{h}$ for the function $f(x) = 3x^2 + 2x$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

Determine $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ for the function $f(x)=3x^2+2x$.

Can anyone please confirm whether this is correct:
\begin{align*}
& = \frac{3x^2+6xh+3h^2+2x+2h-3x^2-2x}{h}\\
& = \frac{6xh+3h^2+2h}{h}\\
& = \frac{h(6x+3h+2)}{h}\\
& = 6x+3h+2
\end{align*}
Do I go a step further by saying:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \to 0} (6x+3h+2) & = 6x+(3 \cdot 0)+2\\
                        & = 6x+2
\end{align*}

I am confused about which answer is the final product and if I have gone a step too far.

Thanks for your help.

Apologies for the lack of information earlier.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you have any issues calculating $f(x+h)-f(x)$ and simplifying?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your post will be better received once you have shown effort in trying to solve the problem. At the very least point out what is confusing to you so we'd have something to go on. People don't take kindly to others trying to get them solve their homework from scratch. No amount of "please" or other pleasantries will change that.

Comment: Hi All, this is my first time posting so I didn't know to add what I had tried. I have lim h approach 0 ((3x^2+2x+h)-3x^2+2x)/h). That's where I get stuck. I am being honest and don't know how to solve this. It's not that I'm asking for it just to be done for me - I was hoping that someone could explain where to even start. Thank you for for clarifying how to use the forum and I'm sorry that my post was offensive to some.

Comment: @Lauren You do have to evaluate the limit, which you did correctly.

Comment: @Lauren You solved the problem. In the beginning you didn't specify what $x$ was so it's natural your end result will depend on it. The limit you found is the derivative at $x$. Upvoted.

Comment: You're correct. Good work!

Answer (score 1):

Given $f(x)=3x^2+2x$:

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}&=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{3(x+h)^2+2(x+h)-2x^2-2x}{h}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{6xh+3h^2+2h}{h}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{h(6x+3h+2)}{h}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\ (6x+3h+2)\\
&=6x+2
\end{align}

You have approached the problem correctly, but it is important to include all necessary notation in your solution (including the $\lim$ in each of your expressions, line after line, until you evaluate the limit by substitution).